# Why does the selenium function elementLocated in node.js throw an error only on Jenkins?

Tags: node.js, selenium, jenkins, automated-tests

I'm using the function `driver.wait(until.elementLocated())` below, written with node.js, as an explicit wait on my Selenium tests to ensure that the pages in my test load properly. When I run the tests from my local CLI they work perfectly, headlessly and with GUI.

```
const loadMyPage = {
  loadThePage: async function(driver) {
    try {
      await driver.wait(
        until.elementLocated(
          By.css("div.radio-select span:nth-child(7)")
        ),
        20000
      );
    } catch (e) {
      console.trace(loadMyPage.loadThePage);
      throw e;
    }
  }
```

However, when I run the tests in Jenkins headlessly I receive the following error every time I use the function `elementLocated()`.

```
TypeError: Wait condition must be a promise-like object, function, or a Condition object[0m[90m
      at Driver.wait (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:928:13)
      at Object.loadMyPage (foobar-tests/page.js:35:20)
      at Context.<anonymous> (foobar-tests/foobar.test.js:32:30)
      at <anonymous>
```

Is there anything specific that could cause this error in Jenkins? I have managed to narrow it down to this specific function, `elementLocated()`.

Comment: Update the question with the relevant _HTML_

Comment: This happens on any HTML, regardless if it's as simple as <body>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a workaround for my issue, however it appears that there is a larger issue at play with selenium. More information on the core issue can be found at https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/5560.

I updated my explicit wait by passing an additional async function, and this cleared up the problem entirely in Jenkins. Example is below.

```
  loadMyPage: async () => {

        //The second async is necessary to run explicit wait functions like the one below.
        //This issue is specific to selenium, more information can be found at https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/5560.
    loadThePage: async () {
        try {
          async driver =>
            await driver.wait(
              until.elementLocated(
                By.css("div.radio-select span:nth-child(7)")
              ),
              10000
            );
        } catch (e) {
          console.trace(loadMyPage.loadThePage);
          throw e;
        }
      }
```

Comment: I was not able to use it but what worked for me was to get `.fn` form the condition function so `until.elementLocated( ...).fn` and it just worked.